# Empty dataset when querying sql server VIEW from excel 2013

Tags: sql-server, excel

When querying sql server view data (it does work when I query a table), I receive only the header but no rows. In sql server profiler I can see that the sql statement looks correct (and I get data from the view when I execute the statement in sql server management studio) but the read and cpu counters are minimal compared to a direct query. There are no linked servers involved, username in profiler is the same for both access methods.

Answer (score 0):

One of the subviews was filtering using for APP_NAME()... which is "Microsoft Office 2013" when one queries from Excel and "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio" when using SSMS. This cleary explains why Excel did not get any rows...sorry for bothering.